# Reading .csv file and get database row values and copy back to another file through SSIS package

Tags: ssis

I have a .csv file containing comma separated values, like SID, phone no etc. I need to get the SID search it in the database (DB2) tables and get some more values if the SID matches and then get all these values and write it in a new file. This should be done through SSIS package. Can anyone help regarding how to approach this? Some sample codes or links with codes will certainly help. Thanks

Comment: If the value exists in the target database, will there be 1 row or multiple rows?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to create a Data Flow and use a `Lookup Transformation` to retrieve the extra info you need: To read .csv file you use a `Flat File Source`.

There is a video about using Lookups: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQ1eM0TUdl0

For more information about the Lookup, check the official documentation on it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx
It is also possible to do that by doing `Merge Joins` which work almost like a join in SQL. However, the `Lookup Transformation` is more efficient, albeit more limited.

Information about performance differences can be seen here: http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/10/21/2289.aspx